# Unable to apply CSS in ngb-tabset

Tags: angular, sass, ng-bootstrap

I am using ngb-tabset across my application and is using ".nav-tabs .nav-link" in my app-component to style the tabs. This works. But I have a situation where in  I need to apply a different style to one of the tabs in a child component. I gave a ID to the parent DIV and applied style like below. But the style applied is the default one. How can I make sure that this particular style is applied for this tab. Please advise.

Below is what I tried.

HTML

`<div id="overview__id" class="col-md-12 col-lg-10 mx-auto">
  <ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab>`

SASS

```
#overview__id .nav-tabs .nav-link
 border: none
 margin-right: 0.25rem
 color: #ffffff !important
```

Comment: please add your full code in html and css